# Refused to execute script from p.adsymptotic.com

Tags: javascript

Has anyone seen this before? I am seeing it recently on my web app. Seems like malicious to me any ideas?

> Refused to execute script from `https://p.adsymptotic.com/d/px/?_pid=16218&_psign=0aa5badf92527f7732e22463d6fa4dbc&coopa=0&gdpr=0&gdpr_consent=&_puuid=bdf06633-bba8-4be4-bfc9-874db632b7e9&_umid=b785f352df2e57e5171ecc189d20e5ab924667d8a8c12c888f53939c09ad8ca3` because its MIME type (`image/gif`) is not executable.

Comment: That's your site's `Content-Security-Policy` doing what it's supposed to do. If that's somehow been injected without your knowledge into your own application, then yes that is a bad thing.

Comment: It looks like some sort of tracking pixel.

Comment: do you have linked in tracking scripts in your app ?

Comment: @GalSamuel yes I do and I was thinking those could cause that, you know something more?

Comment: The linked in code spawns this. verify by temporarily eliminating the linked in code.

Comment: I can confirm Linkedin partner tracking script code is the culprit for me as well, as @GalSamuel suggested.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems LinkedIn partners tracking scripts are spawning this. 
For example I use:

> `https://snap.licdn.com/li.lms-analytics/insight.min.js`